# How to get notification on custom lock screen

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications

I have created a Lock screen and i want to show the notifications of messages,missed call etc on the lock screen for example if i received 2 messages and 3 missed calls then it should display on lock screen.

Anyone please tell me how i can do this?

Comment: Any luck? I wish to do the same as you

Answer (score 0):

you can use `App Widgets` which can also be displayed in the lock screens (maybe not all types).
 
Consider the `android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"` property.

See these

[App Widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

you can make use of flag [FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)

and [This](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/wiki/LockActivity) great example by google.

Hope this helps.